# I wrote the function, but it works inconsistently, R, Coursera, Best Hospital assignment

Tags: r, function

I am learning R and was trying to solve the Coursera Best Hospital assignment. For some reason, my function's results are inconsistent. It gives correct answers only in 4 out of 6 sample outputs. I looked through the internet and already got rid of all the warnings I had along the way. But cannot figure out the function bug. I appreciate your time and any constructive comments you can provide on how to improve the function. Thank you all very much.

```
    best <- function (state, outcome) {

      data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character", 
               na.strings = "Not Available")

      select_o <- if (outcome == "heart attack") {
        "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"
      } else if (outcome == "heart failure") {
        "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"
      } else if (outcome == "pneumonia") {
        "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"
      } else {
        stop("invalid outcome")
      }

      for (i in nrow(data)) {
        if(data$State[i] != state) {
          stop("invalid state")}
      }
        best_data <- data[data$State == state, c("Hospital.Name", select_o)]
        na.omit(best_data)
        best_data[, select_o] <- as.numeric(best_data[, select_o])
        ordered <- order(best_data[, select_o], best_data[, "Hospital.Name"])

        as.character(best_data[, "Hospital.Name"][ordered[1]])

    }
```

When I test sample outputs I get these results:

```
        > best("TX", "heart attack")
        [1] "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER"
```

correct

```
        > best("TX", "heart failure")
        [1] "FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER"
```

correct

```
        > best("MD", "heart attack")
        Error in best("MD", "heart attack") : invalid state
```

it should print " Johns Hopkins Hospital, The" here

```
        > best("MD", "pneumonia")
        Error in best("MD", "pneumonia") : invalid state
```

and "Greater Baltimore Medical Center" here

```
        > best("BB", "heart attack")
        Error in best("BB", "heart attack") : invalid state
```

correct

```
        > best("NY", "hert attack")
        Error in best("NY", "hert attack") : invalid outcome
```

correct

Comment: It's not clear what your function is trying to do. I suggest you edit your question with what the actual goal is, an example of the input data, and what you expect the output to be. Have a read of [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5977215). This will make other people more likely to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The error lies here:

```
for (i in nrow(data)) {
```

Actually, when you apply nrow() function over data.frame, a one-length vector is returned signifying the number of rows in the data.frame.

So, in the above code, when you use `i in nrow(data)`, `i` will have only one value that is the number of rows in `data`.

If you want to iterate over each and every row of the data.frame, change the code to following:

Solution:

```
valid_state <- F
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if(data$State[i] == state){ 
        valid_state <- T
        break
    }
}

if (!valid_state)
    stop("invalid state")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, everyone, the issue was fixed in the below code;

```
  # First, we load "Outcome of Care Measures" data table into R and inspect it:

  outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  head(outcome)
  ncol(outcome)
  nrow(outcome)
  names(outcome)

  # 1. Let's build a simple plot for the 30-day death rates from heart attack (column 11):

  outcome[, 11] <- as.numeric(outcome[, 11])
  hist(outcome[, 11])

  # 2. Now we will create a function searching for the best hospital in state.

  best <- function (state, outcome) {
  my_data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character", na.strings = "Not Available")

  select_o <- if (outcome == "heart attack") {
    "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"
  } else if (outcome == "heart failure") {
    "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"
  } else if (outcome == "pneumonia") {
    "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"
  } else {
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }

  # Let's check state validity
  valid_state <- which(my_data$State == state)

  # we create a loop, if any of the table states names match given state name, 
  # then mark state as valid; if no states match, mark invalid
  for (i in 1:nrow(my_data)) {
    if(my_data$State[i] == state) {
      valid_state
      break} 
    if (length(valid_state) == 0) {
      stop("invalid state")}
  }

  # now we select only observations that match the state and the outcome specified by user
    best_data <- my_data[valid_state, c("Hospital.Name", select_o)] 

  # make sure selected outcome column is numeric:
    best_data[, select_o] <- as.numeric(best_data[, select_o])

  # order our new table by outcome and Hospital.Name
    ordered <- order(best_data[, select_o], best_data[, "Hospital.Name"])

  # To select the Hosital with the lowest mortality rate, we just need to select 
  # the first element in our ordered table
    as.character(best_data[, "Hospital.Name"][ordered[1]])
  }

  # sample inputs:
  best("TX", "heart attack")
  best("TX", "heart failure")
  best("MD", "heart attack")
  best("MD", "pneumonia")
  best("BB", "heart attack")
  best("NY", "hert attack")
```

I posted a full code here: https://github.com/brklngirl/ProgrammingAssignment3/blob/master/best.R

Comment: In future, please [include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing same assignment. Have a look at how I solved my problem.

```
valid_list <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
if (any(valid_list == x) ) {

} else {

    stop("invalid measure")
}

care_outcome <-read_care_outcome()
valid_state <-unique(care_outcome[,7])

if (any(valid_state == state) ) {

} else {

    stop("invalid state")
}
```